# Find differential. Is it the same as finding dy?

Tags: calculus

These questions told me to find the differential at a number when given a specific dx. Wanted to check if my work is right:

1.
$$x = 0, dx = 0.1$$

$$y = e^{\frac{x}{10}}$$
$$y' = e^{\frac{x}{10}} \cdot \frac{1}{10} $$

so

$$dy = e^{\frac{x}{10}} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot 0.1 = \frac{1}{100}$$

Is that right?

2.

$$x = 2, dx = 0.05$$
$$y = \frac{x+1}{x-1}$$
$$ y' = \frac{(x-1) - (x+1)}{(x-1)(x-1)}$$
$$ = \frac{-2}{(x-1)^2}$$

so

$$dy = \frac{-2}{1} \cdot 0.05 = -0.1$$

Comment: You could use $dy=y(x+dx)-y(x)$ if $dx$ is finite.

Comment: how does my work look?

Comment: Yes, that is correct though the notation makes me cringe!  What you are calling "dx" and "dy" are actually approximations to them.  I would rather write $\Delta y= \frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x$.

Comment: but my textbook says dy is the approximation/differential

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The definition of a differential, at least according to Stewart's calculus text, is

$$dy= f'(x)dx,$$
where $dx$ and $x$ are independent variables. What this is providing is a best linear approximation you can get, namely $$f(a+dx)\approx f(a)+dy.$$